# Reuse tips for Android

Tags: android, resources, android-activity, code-reuse

Android resources and their automatically generated references simplify the development of **one** app a great deal. But they also complicate the reuse of Android activities in multiple projects, and in general of any component that uses resources.

[Library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject) are a limited alternative. A project can depend on many library projects, but a library project can't depend on another, and adding additional JAR dependencies is not straightforward.

How do you reuse Android components (not plain old Java code)? Any tips and tricks?

Answer (score 1):

I have some tips, tricks, and tools wrapped up in the [Android Parcel Project](http://andparcel.com).

Comment: If this were an Eclipse plugin I'd be all over it! Using Ruby and Ruby concepts makes it more difficult for a programmer without Ruby background like me to get familiar with the project, but it looks interesting enough to get past that and give it a go.

Comment: @hgpc: Well, I'm not an Eclipse user. I'd be willing to meet somebody halfway with a Java port. I also thought it would be easier to wrap up the Ruby scripts into executables than it turned out to be. :-(